# Alternative to dual-list-box crashing

Tags: lightning-web-components, browser, lightning-duallistbox

I'm using the dual-list-box on LWC and it was working fine but after deploy on the other orgs I have a problem with "too many query rows 50001" because it was just a query without WHERE on accounts, after adding some conditions on WHERE clause, I could reach almost 7000 rows but the problem is that is crashing, including saying that the google chrome stopped responding and after some seconds stop showing this message but when I try to select some values they crash again.

Which alternative is the best seeing this result of 7000 rows?

Maybe a searching input?

Unfortunately I can not add more conditions on WHERE clause because it doesn't have more to add

Comment: will you ever have more than say 50 records in a dual-list-box ? if yes, then you may need to consider other ways on rendering them in the UI. Try using SOSL instead if that works

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're still using Locker Service. Try enabling Lighting Web Security (Setup | Session Settings), it should give you far better performance. That said, for anything more than a few hundred items, consider some kind of autocompletion design. As the user types, denounce with a small delay (250-500ms), then query for matching results. Limit that to a reasonable number. LWC is reasonably fast, I've gotten it to render 10k+ items in a small fraction of a second, but Locker Service is really going to bog down your performance.